# No iteration in nested while statement

Tags: python, arrays, list

[How the loop should iterate.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GQmdC.jpg) I'm a beginner trying to create a Python program to print a word backwards based on old knowledge from a few years ago. It does a few other things but they are just printed statements are don't pose a problem.  Here is my code:

```
count = 0
while count < 100:
    word_var = input("Enter ONE word with NO spaces:")
    def split(word_var):
        return list(word_var)
    word_array = split(word_var)
    m = 0
    i = len(word_array)-1-m
    print("The number of letters in your word is:", i)
    while m < len(word_array):
        if m < i:
            word_array[m], word_array[i - m] = word_array[i - m], word_array[m]
            m = m + 1
        else:
            break
    m = m + 1

    print(''.join(word_array))
    count = count + 1
    print("You've typed:",count,"word(s).")
```

Here is the problem section:

```
        if m < i:
            word_array[m], word_array[i - m] = word_array[i - m], word_array[m]
            m = m + 1
        else:
            break
     m = m + 1
```

My main problem is that it seems like the second while loop is not iterating when the word is more than five letters long. For example, if I input the word "should" into the program I get back out `dhouls.` It seems as if only one interchange of letters is being performed. I figure this is a problem with the if statement in that nested while loop, but I can't seem to find what is wrong with it. I carefully sketched out how I think the if statement works in the photo attached.

Comment: What's the point of `m = m + 1` outside the `while m < len(word_array)` loop?

Comment: Why not just `for m in range(i):`? Then you don't need the `if` and `break`.

Comment: I don't know about the range function, but I'm going to learn. Any more suggestions to clean it up if you don't mind?

Comment: As noted in the answers, it is easy enough to reverse a string. Also note that strings are treated like arrays in python, so having a function like the `split()` you defined that puts them into a list is overkill. (Notably, `split()` is a common string function, so there may be some confusion there.)

Comment: @Barmar sure, but then we could just as easily ignore the algorithm and point out that the entire reversal process could be replaced with `print(word_var[::-1])`. Presumably the goal here is to develop low-level reasoning skills.

Comment: @NathanielFord while strings can be iterated over, they are not *mutable*. OP creates a list (we don't call them "arrays" in Python) in order to be able to swap elements around in place.

Comment: "I carefully sketched out how I think the if statement works in the photo attached." It's hard to read your handwriting, but I think I can make it out. At the bottom of the page, it looks like you have a note `3 < 3 : False` Indeed, 3 is not less than 3. But where did you get the `3`s from? On the left-hand side, something is counting up from 0, and on the right-hand side, something is counting down from 5 (the last valid index for the list). Yes? Now, look closely - what part of your program is supposed to correspond to that? Do you see a problem with it? Hint: when does `i` ever change?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You've shown quite a few [debugging skills](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) already, which is very good for a new programmer. As it happens, the problem was just a simple oversight. That happens to even the best of us. In the future, though, please try a *discussion forum* if you are just looking for "another pair of eyes". Stack Overflow is for when, after your attempt at debugging, you've run into a conceptual problem - you know exactly what is wrong, but can't figure out what to do about it.

Answer (score 2):

Your `if` condition is wrong. You want to compare the two indices that you will use in the list, but the second one is not `i`, but `i-m`. So change it to:

```
if m < i - m:
```

This corrects your issue. It should be noted that in Python you can reverse string just like this:

```
print(word_var[::-1])
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two issues:

1. The counting of the letters isn't correct. You should just output the length of `word_array`.
2. You're iterating the `while` loop too many times. You should terminate it when `m` equals or exceeds `len(word_array) // 2`. Otherwise, you'll unreverse the letters and get the original word back.

```py
i = len(word_array)-1
print("The number of letters in your word is:", len(word_array))
while m < len(word_array) // 2:
    word_array[m], word_array[i - m] = word_array[i - m], word_array[m]
    m = m + 1
```

This outputs:

```
Enter ONE word with NO spaces:should
The number of letters in your word is: 6
dluohs
You've typed: 1 word(s).
```

Answer (score 0):

I like your project and appreciate your efforts.
This a another way to reverse a string using a ***list*** variable and the ***insert()*** method.
word_array = []

```
word_var = input('Your word : ')
word_array = []

for c in word_var:
    word_array.insert(0, c)

word_reversed = ''.join(word_array)
print(word_var, '->', word_reversed)
```

***output :***

```
should -> dluohs
```